# GFCI not working. Other receptacles do

Tags: gfci

I wired up 4 new double gang boxes for a fish room I’m building. On the first double gang box in the fish room I tied into an existing outlet on the same wall that faces opposite for the room on the other side of the wall. I then wired the outlet that shares the double gang box with the gfci. I made sure everything was wired correctly. (Line and load terminals). And then continued the wiring for the next 6 outlets. With the breaker back on the gfci led light is on but the gfci outlet doesn’t work but all the other outlets down the line do work. I tried resetting the the gfci, installing a different gfci, and double checked all the wiring. What would be causing this?

Comment: We'll probably need a wiring diagram or clear photos. It's hard to diagnose circuitry with what we have to work with here. Your assertion that "everything was wired correctly" is contradicted by the evidence.

Comment: When you trip the GFCI (test) do the the six outlets downstream shutdown as they should?

Answer (score 2):

### Move all wires to LINE

Placing any wires on LOAD is incorrect unless you have a *very specific reason* to do that.

"I have more wires to attach and don't know where else to put them" is *not* a specific reason.

If the GFCI fails with all wires on LINE, then the GFCI is defective.

If you have a specific reason to use LOAD, then attach the LINE wires first, stop and checkpoint your work, assure that the GFCI works in all respects.   Then attach LOAD.

Answer (score 0):

So are you saying you put a GFCI outlet on a GFCI protected branch circuit?

Have you tried pressing the test and reset on the new outlet? With some brands of GFCI’s they need both the test and reset to be cycled to activate them after losing power or for the first time install this could be a problem if you have this type as each time you hit the test it may trip the breakers GFCI function if you have a GFCI breaker.

If the outlet is the only GFCI 
At a minimum press the test then reset and it may work.